# units in math, cross product

Tags: cross-product

The cross product of two vectors has length equal to the area of the parallelogram they generate.

The cross product is also a vector and thus has dimensions. But the units of those dimensions are units of area, such as m2.

My question is - this vector can't be in the same vector space as the original vectors multiplied, right?

What does adding units to dimension do to a vector space?

Comment: Probably related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector

Comment: ... or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector.

Comment: A similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705954/cross-products-versus-units-of-measure

Comment: Also seems helpful: [mathoverflow.net/questions/4069/](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4069/bivectors-in-3-and-4-dimensions)...

Comment: @JoonatanTalviste You might also find [Muphrid's answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269896/how-is-area-a-vector/269900#269900) informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- using a vector to write the cross product is just a 3D convention to remind you it has 3 independent components. It's more naturally represented as a bivector or as a rank-2 tensor, but there's a duality between these and vectors in 3D.

**Scale invariance/tensors in physics**

The formal way of expressing your concern -- that the cross product has different "units" from other vectors in your space -- is that the cross product *doesn't behave like a vector under scaling*. Under scaling, a vector is supposed to scale as $v\to\lambda v$, because lengths scale that way, and areas scale as $t\to\lambda^2t$. The cross product scales as an area, so it makes a sucky vector.

This is sort of related to the definition of tensors in physics (specifically in relativity) -- a tensor is an object that transforms as a tensor under specific transformations, specifically Lorentz transformations (skews in the t-x/t-y/t-z plane and rotations in the other three, x-y/y-z/z-x). So scalars are invariant under Lorentz transformations, vectors transform as $\Lambda_\mu^{\bar\mu}v^\mu$, rank-2 tensors transform as $\Lambda_\mu^{\bar\mu}\Lambda_\nu^{\bar\nu}t^{\mu\nu}$, etc. So it's not enough to have the right number of components -- because this can be gamed with symmetries, like it is for the cross product (which has nine components, but only three independent one) -- you need to transform in the right way.

It's a bit more complicated with scaling, because different scalars transform differently (lengths scale like vectors, areas scale like rank-2 tensors), but the idea is the same -- the cross product is not a vector in the physics sense, although it is in the math sense. But nobody in math cares about the cross product anyway.

Comment: Very informative answer. Sorry for the *very* late feedback!